# Conway game of life loop fix

Tags: f#

Hello guys i'm currently working on a project to create Conway game of life using f#.
my problem is that i want to make the game run in a loop that continuously changing the matrix when i press the start button and it should loop until i press the stop button.

to explain my code i can say that we start in the `loop` function and wait until i press a button then the button press will give me what type of action i have taken then for example if i press start i will get the start action then in the match i will call the function that is needed for this action which is the `startbutton` function.

the problem i'm having now is that when i start the `startbutton` function it loops as it should be but i don't get any changes in the display. when i debugged this code from my understanding is that i'm changing in the list i sent not in the main list and that why i'm not getting any thing on the screen and this maybe wrong or not the main issue but i don't find any other reason for the behavior i'm seeing. so i was thinking about changing the structure i have right now but i just cant find a good way to make it work because right now even if it will loop on the correct list i will be stuck on the `startbutton` function and what that mean that my other buttons will not work like the stop button for example.

in summary what i want is to be able to make the game run and never stops until i press the stop button and then the game should stop or if i start the game and press the next button instead of the start button the loop that is happening in the `startbutton` should loop one time which is equal to one step in the game or one life cycle.

so do you have any idea how i should fix this issue or how can i improve the structure of what i have or maybe you have a solution that does not require to change the structure ?

the code below is what i have until now and u can use this code to see how the game works in the GUI maybe that give you some ideas how to solve the problem

```
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing


module Gui = 

let form = new Form(Width = 528, Height = 572)
let matrixlabel = Array2D.init 16 16 (fun y x -> (new Label(Width = 32, Height = 32, BackColor = Color.White, 
                                                            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Left = 32*x, Top = 32*y)))
let lblList = matrixlabel |> Seq.cast<Label> |> Seq.fold (fun l n -> n :: l) []
let btnAdd0 = new Button(Text="Start", Top = 513, Height = 20, Width = 40)
let btnAdd1 = new Button(Text="Stop", Top = 513, Height = 20, Width = 40, Left = 40)
let btnAdd2 = new Button(Text="Next", Top = 513, Height = 20, Width = 40, Left = 80)
let btnAdd3 = new Button(Text="Steps", Top = 513, Height = 20, Width = 40, Left = 120)
let btnlist = [btnAdd0; btnAdd1; btnAdd2; btnAdd3;]
let text = new TextBox(Text="", Top = 513, Left = 160);


for y in 0 .. 15 do
    for x in 0 .. 15 do
        form.Controls.AddRange [| matrixlabel.[y,x] |]

for i in btnlist do 
    form.Controls.AddRange [| i |]

form.Controls.AddRange [| text |]
```

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open Gui
open System.Drawing
open FSharpx.Control.Observable

type Action = 
| Start 
| Stop 
| Next 
| Steps of int
| Pnt of Point

module Main =
// making sure that all the cells in the createSearchList is inside the matrix we have
let inRange (s : int) (a : int) y x  = 
    match y with 
    | 0 when s = -1 -> false
    | 15 when s = 1 -> false
    | _ -> match x with 
           | 0 when a = -1 -> false
           | 15 when a = 1 -> false
           | _ -> true

// create a small list contaning all the neighbors of the cell we want to check if it will live or not until the next gen
let createSearchList y x (list : Label [,]) =
    [for i in -1..1 do 
     for j in -1..1 do 
     if (((i <> y || j <> x) && (i <> 0 || j <> 0)) && (inRange (i) (j) y x) = true) 
     then yield (list.[y+i, x+j])] 

// count the amount of living neighbors
let rec chek (list : Label List) counter = 
    match list with 
    | head::tail when head.BackColor = Color.Black -> chek tail (counter+1)
    | head::tail when head.BackColor = Color.White -> chek tail counter
    | [] -> counter
        

// create a new list contating how our main list should look like in the next generation 
let checkLabel (labels:Label [,]) = 
    labels
    |> Array2D.mapi (fun e r u -> match u with 
                                  | u when u.BackColor = Color.Black -> match chek (createSearchList e r labels) 0 with 
                                                                        | x when x < 2 || x > 3 -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.White, 
                                                                                                                BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                                                   
                                                                        | x when x = 2 || x = 3 -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.Black, 
                                                                                                                BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                                                   
                                                                        | _ -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.Black, 
                                                                                            BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                               
                                  | u when u.BackColor = Color.White -> match chek (createSearchList e r labels) 0 with 
                                                                        | x when x < 2 || x > 3 -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.White, 
                                                                                                                BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                                                                
                                                                        | x when x = 3 -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.Black, 
                                                                                                        BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                                          
                                                                        | _ -> new Label(Width = u.Width, Height = u.Height, BackColor = Color.White, 
                                                                                            BorderStyle = u.BorderStyle, Left = u.Left, Top = u.Top)
                                                                               
                                  )

// changing the color of each cell in the main list to match the list we created for the next gen 
let changeLabel (labels : Label [,]) (l : Label [,]) =
    labels
    |> Array2D.mapi (fun e r u -> match u with 
                                  | u when u.BackColor = Color.Black -> l.[e,r].BackColor <- Color.Black
                                  | u when u.BackColor = Color.White -> l.[e,r].BackColor <- Color.White
                    )

let eventType action =
    let timer = Timers.Timer(1000.)
    match action with 
    Start -> timer.Start()
             timer.Elapsed
        
                      
//loops and every generation (loop) is 1 sec
let rec startbutton (l : Label [,]) (steps : int) (start : bool) (action) = async{
    let event = Async.AwaitEvent (eventType action) |> Async.Ignore
    Async.RunSynchronously event

    let labels = checkLabel l 
    changeLabel labels l 
    
    return! startbutton labels (steps) start action
}


// the main loop that controlls every button click 
let rec loop (l : Label [,]) (runType : IObservable<Action>) = async{
    let! action = Async.AwaitObservable(runType)

    match action with 
    | Pnt(location) -> let indexX = location.X/32
                       let indexY = location.Y/32
                       if l.[indexY, indexX].BackColor = Color.Black then 
                           l.[indexY, indexX].BackColor <- Color.White
                       else 
                           l.[indexY, indexX].BackColor <- Color.Black
                       return! loop l runType
    | Stop -> return! loop l runType
    | Start -> return! startbutton (l) (0) (true) (action)
    | _ -> return! loop l runType
}

module GuiInterface = 
    //Here we define what we will be observing (clicks)
    let check (element : string) = 
        match element with 
        | x when x = "Start" -> Start
        | x when x = "Stop" -> Stop
        | x when x = "Next" -> Next
        | x when x = "Steps" -> Steps((text.Text |> int))

    let rec lblClick (list : Label List) = 
       match list with 
       | [x] ->  (Observable.map (fun _-> Pnt(x.Location)) (x.Click))
       | head::tail -> Observable.merge (Observable.map (fun _-> Pnt(head.Location)) (head.Click)) (lblClick (tail))
       | [] -> failwith "empty"

    let rec btnClick (listbtn : Button List) (listlbl : Label List) = 
       match listbtn with 
       | [x] -> Observable.merge (Observable.map (fun _-> (check (x.Text))) (x.Click)) (lblClick (listlbl))
       | head::tail -> Observable.merge (Observable.map (fun _-> (check (head.Text))) (head.Click)) (btnClick (tail) (listlbl)) 
       | [] -> failwith "empty"


Async.StartImmediate (loop (matrixlabel) (GuiInterface.btnClick (btnlist) (lblList))); 
Application.Run(form)
```